# Can not add elements to ArrayList<Integer>

Tags: java, arraylist, integer

So I am trying to create a ArrayList of Integers and then iterate variables into it. Only the first value that I specify is being added.

```
 private ArrayList<Integer> heights(String detail) {
        ArrayList<Integer> heights = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        heights.add(0);
        switch(detail) {
            case "L": for(Integer i = 100; i <= 1000; i=+50) { heights.add(i); } break;
            case "H": for(Integer i = 100; i <= 1000; i=+25) { heights.add(i); } break;
        }
        return heights;
    }
```

Value of heights("H"):

heights: [0]

Comment: What is the value of `detail`? If it is neither `L` nor `H` then there is nothing else to add to the list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Problem is in for loop.
Use `int` instead of `Integer` class....

The code below works properly...

```
import java.util.*;  
class Test{
        private ArrayList<Integer> heights(String detail) {
            ArrayList<Integer> heights = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            heights.add(0);
            switch(detail) {
                case "L": for(int i = 100; i <= 1000; i=i+50) { heights.add(i); } break;
                case "H": for(int i = 100; i <= 1000; i=i+25) { heights.add(i); } break;
            }
            return heights;
        }
     public static void main(String args[]){
            Test t = new Test();
            System.out.println(t.heights("H"));
         }
    }
```

Comment: @GhostCat Updated answer, Thanks for Correcting me

Comment: You might want to explain why this works, but definitely better than before.

Comment: Do edit this to explain the problem to which you refer.